# Changing the name of a protocol.h file breaks the code

Tags: ios, xcode, refactoring, protocols

When I change the name of a protocol file, the project does not regocnize it any more. Is that normal behavior? Further more, when I refactor the protocol name from the .h file, it changes everything fine (in the code), but not the actual file name..

How can I solve this?

thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Change the file name (in the Project and in The File System) you have to rename it in the project

Perform a 'Slow' Double click on the file name in Project

When you rename the File make sure you don't just change a Capital to lower case or vise-versa, OSX doesn't allow this as it tends to be case insensitive.

eg

Payment.h -> payment.h                    WONT WORK

Payment.h -> Payment1.h -> payment.h      WORKS

'Slow' Double Click: 1 sec pause between clicks